# What determines the amount of data you would get from a sequencing experiment?

Tags: dna-sequencing, rna-sequencing

When someone performs a sequencing experiment, what determines how much sequencing data you get from the machine (Illumina, PacBio, Nanopore, etc). Or maybe, put differently, how does the machine know that it is done?

Answer (score 1):

On an Illumina machine, the instrument runs as many cycles as you tell it to.  If you tell it to run 150 cycles, you will get 150-mers as output.

Comment: Thanks for this, that explains read-length to an extent but what explains sequencing depth?

Comment: Having more reads for your sample, which you get by giving your sample a higher % of the space on the flow cell.